# Powershell - Can I copy only the changed part of a file to a command prompt?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to link two audio players' playlists so that, while one generates a playlist and saves to its own M3U file, the other (the old winamp) is somehow sent each new track as it is added via the command prompt /ADD tool. Or other means, if there's a better way.

Is this possible with Powershell? To reiterate, I need it to monitor the first program's M3U file, then as the first program dynamically adds each new track and updates itself, Powershell would send each entry to winamp via command line. Is this possible? Just asking directly since I'm a new user and am not clear if it can parse out just the new information as it is added in real-time, or close to it.

Each program has unique plug-ins so I am trying to find a way to combine them to obtain use of both sets of features at the same time.

Comment: This depends entirely on the format of the m3u data but to point you in the right direction maybe consider using something like FileWatcher - https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher to trigger a part of your script that will compare/extract the last few lines and send it to cmd

Comment: [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Tail` allows you to keep waiting for new lines to be added to a file; pipe that to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), where you can make the WinAmp CLI calls.